# pass exact url to Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I must make get request `http://192.168.43.240/n/LED=OFF` but retrofit makes    `http://192.168.43.240/n?/LED=OFF`. It adds question mark after /n.

```
    @GET("/n")
fun searchRepos(
    @Query(value = "/LED") query: String
): Call<RepoSearchResponse>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: use `@Query("LED")` instead that's all

Comment: tried did not help

Comment: Ohh I misread the request. Check my answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrofit adds the question mark to indicate the beginning of the query parameters segment. What you are trying to achieve only contains path parameters. So you can use `@Path` instead of `@Query`. For example like the following

```
@GET("/n/LED={led}")
fun searchRepos(@Path("led") led: String): Call<RepoSearchResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

> @GET("n") fun searchRepos(@Query("LED") query: string):
>   Call

Comment: i think your problems is on your localhost url example :

http://192.168.43.240/n?=LED=OFF

Comment: after n there should not be question mark, I do not know how to remove it